# Recommendation System Method

Tags: algorithm, recommendation-engine

I will design a social network site for football teams (like soccercv) built with the concept recommending
opponent match based on their attributes (i.e location, age of player, number of wins, etc)..

following some of provisions :

1. location nearby (I will use G-map for get location latitude, longitude and distance)
2. Have same age of player and gender (similarity attributes)
3. number of wins (some top-N)

overview (example) :

[image]

I have search some paper for reference :

- [Recommending Friends and Locations Based on Individual Location History](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/122435/recomfriend-zheng-published.pdf)
- [A Survey on Recommendations in Location-based Social Networks](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/191797/Recommendations%20in%20Location-based%20Social%20Networks.pdf)

But I've not found the proper method for my case, method that does not require a rating from user. Does anybody know a method or algorithm for my case?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a (linear) combination of geographical proximity, age proximity, and skill proximity, e.g. based on TrueSkill?

See http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/trueskill/